# how to obtain Explain object from solrj?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I'm switching from lucene to solr and I'm querying it with solrj.

After a query I'd like to obtain the explain and I executed this code:

```
        QueryResponse queryResult = solrClient.query(collection, query, POST);
        List<SolrDocument> recommended = queryResult.getResults();
        Map<String, String> explainMap = queryResult.getExplainMap();
        Map<String, Object> debugMap = queryResult.getDebugMap();
```

The explainMap contains the explanation of my query as a String.

Is it possible to obtain an object of explanation to avoid parsing the string?

For example I'd like to extract all the fields that matched and their value (without score and its composition).

My documents have only one textual field and many categorical or numeric fields.

Comment: if you are getting it in the form of string...it is good for you to read...what is the need to convert the same to Object....?

Comment: I'd like to produce a more compact explain to return to the user, containing which fields and values are matched by the result. Please note that my data have not only one text field, but also other metadata, which are numeric or categorical

Comment: I dont think so there is any provision for that...But If you could how what exactly its is printing for you and what exactly you are expecting then somebody could help...